# How can I close the modal in parent according to the data from child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am opening two js files to import stripe function following the tutorial. My stripe payment will appear in a modal. How can I close the modal after I receive successful payment message in the child?

The codes are as follow:
Parent (some codes are eliminated for easy reading)

```
<Modal isOpen={modalPurchase} toggle={togglePurchase}>
     <Stripe/>                                    
</Modal>
```

The Child:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js"
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js'
import "./Stripe.css"
import PaymentForm from './PaymentForm'


const PUBLIC_KEY = "pk_test_"

const stripeTestPromise = loadStripe(PUBLIC_KEY)

const sendPaymentFormToStripe = () => {
    setPaymentSuccess(true)
}
export default function Stripe() {
  
    
    return (
        <Elements stripe={stripeTestPromise} >
            <PaymentForm />
        </Elements>
    )
};
```

Child of Stripe:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { CardElement, useElements, useStripe } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js"
import * as axios from 'axios'
import { Button } from 'reactstrap'
import "./Stripe.css"

const CARD_OPTIONS = {
    iconStyle: "solid",
    style: {
        base: {
            iconColor: "#c4f0ff",
            color:"fff",
            fontWeight: 500,
            fontSize: "16px",
            fontSmoothing:"antialiased",
        },
        invaild: {
            iconColor: "#ffc7ee",
            color: "ffc7ee"
        }
    }
}

export default function PaymentForm() {
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false)
    const stripe = useStripe()
    const elements = useElements()

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const { error, paymentMethod } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
            type: "card",
            card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
        })


        if (!error) {
            try {
                const { id } = paymentMethod
                const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/checkout', {
                    amount: 500,
                    id
                })

                if (response.data.success) {
                    console.log('Successful payment')
                    setSuccess(true)
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('Error', error)
            }
        } else {
            console.log(error.message)
        }
    }


    return (
        <div>
            {!success ?
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <fieldset className="FormGroup">
                        <div className="FormRow">
                            <CardElement options={CARD_OPTIONS} />
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <Button>Pay</Button>
                </form >
                :
                <div>
                    <h2>Successful</h2>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way could be passing `togglePurchase` function as props to `Stripe` and `PaymentForm` components. So your code becomes:

Parent:

```
<Modal isOpen={modalPurchase} toggle={togglePurchase}>
   <Stripe toggle={togglePurchase}/>                                    
</Modal>
```

Stripe:

```
...
export default function Stripe(props) {

  return (
      <Elements stripe={stripeTestPromise} >
          <PaymentForm toggle={props.toggle}/>
      </Elements>
   )
};
```

PaymentForm:

```
...
export default function PaymentForm(props) {
  ...
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
       ...
       if (response.data.success) {
          console.log('Successful payment')
          setSuccess(true)
          props.toggle()  //<-- call toggle function 
       }
       ...
  }
}
```